# How to call external JavaScript function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small chunk of code I can't seem to get working. I am building a website and using JavaScript for the first time. I have my JavaScript code in an external file 'Marq_Msg.js' which looks like this:

```
var Messages = new Array();
Messages[0] = "This is message 1";
Messages[1] = "This is message 2";
Messages[2] = "This is message 3";
Messages[3] = "This is message 4";  

function scroll_messages()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < Messages.length; i++)
        document.write(Message[i]); 
}
```

and in my HTML file 'Index.html' I am trying to call it like this:

```
    <div id="logo">
        <marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" loop="true" height="100%" width="100%">
        <strong><font color="white"><script src="Marq_Msg.js">scroll_messages()</script></font></strong>
        </marquee>
    </div>
```

The 'logo' div is a CSS piece that I'm trying to marquee inside of. If I put the code embedded inside the 'head' tag and call it, it works perfectly! There are a few other things id like to do with this code (like space the messages out a little) but I can't get the code to work in the first place. I've also tried adding:

```
<script src="Marq_Msg.js"></script>
```

in the 'head' tag with a separate call, that was a no go. I also tried instead using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Marq_Msg.js">scroll_messages()</script>
```

Hell, i even had the function try returning a string (even hardcoded a simple "hello" to be returned) but that didnt work either with and without the 'type':

```
//Marq_Msg.js
function scroll_messages()
{
   return "hello";
}

//index.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="Marq_Msg.js">document.write(scroll_messages())</script>
```

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! I've looked all over Google, and every site I find wants to do it using some 'form'. I just want messages to be displayed across, no form attached.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="Marq_Msg.js">scroll_messages()</script>` worked for me for some reason.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If a `<script>` has a `src` then the text content of the element *will be not be executed as JS* (although it will appear in the DOM).

You need to use multiple script elements.

1. a `<script>` to load the external script
2. a `<script>` to hold your inline code (with the call to the function in the external script)

   scroll_messages();

Comment: Update: I did a more basic page only emcompassing the marquee...and it works. Your answer works perfectly, I thank you for that!!! I think it may be a font color or....idk something. Ill fiddle with it a bit more. Thank you again. You dont happen to think it has anything to do on under what `<div>` tag its under do you?

Comment: Hello. I did that: I used two scripts blocks , one using src="./functions.js" and another block using one function created there: getAnswers(); - But console says that the function is not defined... I did'nt understand your answer. Could u add a little more details? I'm sorry, i am also very new to JavaScript...

Answer (score 15):

In Layman terms, you need to include external js file in your HTML file & thereafter you could directly call your JS method written in an external js file from HTML page.
Follow the code snippet for insight:-

caller.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="letMeCallYou()" value="run external javascript">
```

external.js

```
function letMeCallYou()
{
    alert("Bazinga!!!  you called letMeCallYou")
}
```

Result :
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If anyone still has the reference error is probably because you are loading your Javascript with defer, or it's in the bottom of the body so when the function gets called your function still doesn't exist.