# How can I reference an method in HTML that is in an object

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to know how to reference a method in HTML that is in an object in my JavaScript file, or if that is even good practice.

HTML

```
<select class="ranking" name="rank" id="" onchange = "if(this.selectedIndex) Someobj.Search.chosenRank();">
    <option value="Last_Updated">Last Updated</option>
    <option value="Relevance">Relevance</option>
    <option value="Distance">Distance</option>
</select>
<script src="static 'main/js/search.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
Someobj.Search = {
    chosenRank: function(){
        alert("you chose" + this.selectedIndex );
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530954/how-to-call-external-javascript-function-in-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call external javascript function in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530954/how-to-call-external-javascript-function-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally better to separate code from your HTML. I'd recommend something along the lines of:

```
document.querySelector(".ranking").addEventListener("change", Someobj.Search.chosenRank);
```