# Calling a Javascript function from an external js file in the html file

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, browserify

I am unable to call a function from external javascript file in an HTML file. Kindly suggest me where am I making a mistake...

I have updated the js file.

**File 1: A.js**

```
    (function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){
function sayHello(){
    console.log("hello");
}





},{}]},{},[1]);
```

**File 2: index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <button onclick="sayHello()">click Me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle1.js"></script>
  </div>
<div>
  <button type="button">rotate me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, Whenever I run the html file, I get an error after clicking the button that sayHello() is not found.

The command: browserify A.js -o bundle1.js

Kindly help me spotting the error!

Comment: you can remove the bad type="" in HTML5, or fix it with "text/javascript"

Comment: also, after fixing it, I suggest you to move your `<script>` tag or inside the `<head>` or to the complete bottom of `<body>` it makes your code more readable

Comment: A similar question was asked & answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530954/how-to-call-external-javascript-function-in-html)

Comment: if browserify wraps your code inside a function, the sayHello is no longer in the global scope, so inline attribute can't use it. You can add a click event listener with document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', sayHello) on the button (good), or you could make your sayHello global with window.sayHello = sayHello; (bad)

Comment: @progysm Hello, I followed your suggestion, but whenever I try to run using ng serve on node.js, the browserified  code is not loaded.
Secondly, if I run html file directly on the browser without node or other application, then no error is thrown but the nothing is printed on the console.

Also, if i do this: document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){console.log("hello"}), then hello is printed on the console.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the script type to `"text/javascript"` or simply omit it as it is no longer needed in HTML5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <button onclick="sayHello()">click Me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="A.js"></script>
  </div>
<div>
  <button type="button">rotate me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am embarrassed that i missed this change!! thanks for the help

Comment: I have made a change to the code. And now again i am getting the same error. It would be great if any suggestion can be provided.